# Memory Error when concatenating multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I'm trying to concatenate several hundred CSV files, each 100 to 500mb in size. They all have different columns (10 to 300 columns per CSV) save for 1 (ID_KEY). I've used the following function:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
def concat_all(my_csv_list, data_path, save_to):    
    datasets = []
    for csv in my_csv_list:
        df = dd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_path,csv), 
                         dtype=str)
        datasets.append(df)
    result = dd.concat(datasets)
    result.to_csv(save_to)
```

However memory usage quickly jumps to 90% and the script stops with a Memory Error. I can't just concatenate all the CSV line by line because I need new columns to be filled with NAs. I guess I could still technically handle that "manually" (keeping the index of columns and adding empty commas to each line i'm copying), but I'd much prefer a cleaner, simpler solution...

Comment: check `getsizeof(datasets)`. which result in bytes. for every loop. you may get some idea.

Comment: `from sys import getsizeof`

Comment: since i'm using dask dataframes won't be loaded into memory during the loop. getsizeof won't give me much info.

Comment: Have you consider use the library mentioned [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4105)?